# Change the check box position

Tags: html, asp.net, css, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

In the view I've browse file and check box currenlty the check Box is above the browse control and I want it to be in the **left** side of it,how should I change it?

```
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Cert, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @if (Model.Certificate !=null)
            {
                <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" disabled="disabled" />
            }
            else
            {
                <input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled" />
            }
            <input type="file" name=ficateFile />
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing your full code and css this is a tricky thing to answer however perhaps you could try this?

```
input[type=checkbox], input[type=file] {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

If that doesnt work you could allways split the checkbox and file upload into 2 columns eg

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-2"></div> <!-- Label -->
    <div class="col-md-2"></div> <!-- Checkbox -->
    <div class="col-md-8"></div> <!-- File Upload -->
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks ,where should I put the first code that you provide,in diffrent file?

Comment: You should add it to your sites .css file or alternatively add it in a `<style type="text/css"></style>` element on the page. That said you should change the css selectors to be something more specific before add the code to your stylesheet.

Comment: Thanks Voted Up This is exactly what I want!one last question can I add little space between the check box and the browse button?

Comment: You can do this by adding a margin to the checkbox, try adding this to your styles `input[type=checkbox] { display: inline-block; margin-right: 10px; }`

Answer (score 1):

I cant see your css, but you should apply some css changes. See in element inspector where elements floating depends on parrent element and adjust float. You can apply custom css class if you dont wont to compromise your css.

Answer (score 1):

`<input style="display: inline" type="file" name=ficateFile />` should work. Also change the second div to span if you want all 3 elements on the same line.

Comment: Thanks I try it But there is no attribute with name display...any other idea?

Comment: Oops my bad... display should be in style attribute. Try it now, I have updated my answer.